# Как использовать в колбеке результат функции, в которую он передается js

Tags: javascript, callback

Есть такой псевдокод:

```
const callback = (data) => {
  if(valid(data){
    save(data)
    win.close()
  } else {
    alert('данные не валидны')
  }
}

const win = openWin(data, callback)
```

То есть в колбеке функии `openWin` используется результат этой функции. При таком использовании пишет ошибку

```
cannot access variable before initialization
```

хотя колбек не может вызваться до того как переменная `win` будет инициализирована.

Если объявить `win` перед колбеком `var` или `let`, а потом установить, в колбеке `win` захватывается как `undefined`.

Как правильно поступить в такой ситуации, чтобы получить доступ к результату функции в колбеке?

Минимальный рабочий пример:

```js
const openWin = (data, callback) => {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    callback(data+1)
  }, 1000)

  return {
    close(){console.log('method close was called')}
  }
}

const callback = (data) => {
  if(data > 1){
    // здесь надо получить доступ к win
    win.close()
  } else {
    alert('data is invalid')
  }
}

const win = openWin(1, callback)
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, приведите [mcve] вместо псевдокода

Comment: Если функция `openWin` не передает результат своего вычисления в колбек - колбек никак не сможет его использовать. Если, конечно, результат не будет находиться в некой переменной из общей области видимости...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ghd3QmVB

Comment: Минимальный пример должен демонстрировать проблему. А он вообще-то работает.

Answer (score 0):

> Как использовать в колбеке результат функции, в которую он передается

Например вот так...

```js
const openWin = (data, callback) => {
  const res = {
    close() {
      console.log('method close was called')
    }
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(data + 1, res)
  }, 1000)

  return res
}

const callback = (data, res) => {
  if (data > 1) {
    // тут можно использовать res
    res.close()
  } else {
    alert('data is invalid')
  }
}

const win = openWin(1, callback)
```